# perl array/hash to php

Tags: php, arrays, perl, hash

Trying to convert a perl script to php.

In perl I have a hash like this

```
my %SPEC=(
odmiles           => ['OD Miles','Mileage','odmiles:ecmmiles','num'],
ecmmiles          => ['ECM Miles',0,'','num',' ECM'],
cdl               => ['CDL','CDL']);
```

I can access the data like so:

```
$SPEC{ecm}[3]  # output = num
```

Since a hash in perl does not run in order I'll do a simple array

```
@ORD=('odmiles','ecmmiles','cdl');
```

then loop

```
foreach my $S (@ORD) {
  print $S." = ".$SPEC{$S}[0]."<br />";
  }
```

I can do similar with php but having issue accessing elements past [0] in my hash.

Comment: My canonical response to "translate from X to Y": http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting; nothing special about this link, there are probably several comparison tables like this

Comment: I am not asking to have my code translated. I am asking how to access the elements past the first in my hash using php. i.e. Mileage, position[1] in above example

Comment: Here's what I have $array = array("odmiles" => "OD Miles"); $array["odmiles"];

Comment: @chrisrth Or perhaps `$SPEC = array("odmiles" => array("OD Miles", "Mileage", ...));` Not sure if that is valid PHP.

Comment: @chrisrth I am not sure I am understanding you correctly.. you know that `$SPEC{$S}[0]` gives the first element, and you don't know that `$SPEC{$S}[1]` gives the second, and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$SPEC = array(
  'odmiles'           => array('OD Miles','Mileage','odmiles:ecmmiles','num'),
  'ecmmiles'          => array('ECM Miles',0,'','num',' ECM'),
  'cdl'               => array('CDL','CDL')
);
```

Accessing elements would then work something like this:

```
echo $SPEC['odmiles'][0]; // 'OD Miles'
echo $SPEC['odmiles'][1]; // 'Mileage'
```